# cannot resolve constructor jsonobjectrequest

Tags: java, android, json, import

> The error is:

```
 "cannot resolve constructor jsonobjectrequest(int,
 java.lang.string, null, anonymous
 com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONObject>,anonymous
 com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener)
```

Code Error:

> // Nueva petición JSONObject

```
    jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL_BASE + URL_JSON,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    items = parseJson(response);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            }
    );
```

Code Class:

```
    // Atributos
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest;
    private static final String URL_BASE = "http://servidorexterno.site90.com/datos";
    private static final String URL_JSON = "/social_media.json";
    private static final String TAG = "PostAdapter";
    List<Post> items;

    public PostAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context,0);

        // Crear nueva cola de peticiones
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        // Nueva petición JSONObject
        jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL_BASE + URL_JSON,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        items = parseJson(response);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                }
        );

        // Añadir petición a la cola
        requestQueue.add(jsArrayRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items != null ? items.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        // Referencia del view procesado
        View listItemView;

        //Comprobando si el View no existe
        listItemView = null == convertView ? layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.post,
                parent,
                false) : convertView;


        // Obtener el item actual
        Post item = items.get(position);

        // Obtener Views
        TextView textoTitulo = (TextView) listItemView.
                findViewById(R.id.textoTitulo);
        TextView textoDescripcion = (TextView) listItemView.
                findViewById(R.id.textoDescripcion);
        final ImageView imagenPost = (ImageView) listItemView.
                findViewById(R.id.imagenPost);

        // Actualizar los Views
        textoTitulo.setText(item.getObjectno());
        textoDescripcion.setText(item.getDrivername());

        // Petición para obtener la imagen
        ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(
                URL_BASE + item.getObjectname(),
                new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        imagenPost.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }, 0, 0, null,null,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        imagenPost.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error en respuesta Bitmap: "+ error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        // Añadir petición a la cola
        requestQueue.add(request);


        return listItemView;
    }

    public List<Post> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
        // Variables locales
        List<Post> posts = new ArrayList();
        JSONArray jsonArray= null;

        try {
            // Obtener el array del objeto
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                try {
                    JSONObject objeto= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Post post = new Post(
                            objeto.getString("titulo"),
                            objeto.getString("descripcion"),
                            objeto.getString("imagen"));


                    posts.add(post);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: "+ e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return posts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing null as the third argument is the cause for error. Try passing an empty string. You can find the solution from the link: http://java-lang-programming.com/en/articles/33

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, "", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

      }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

      }
  });
```